HOWM: Is there a way to create a new note without the link to the original file?
In howm, C-c , c creates a new note with a link to the original file like this

Any time I need to create a todo item by adding + after the date stamp, I need to delete the link with C-k. Is there a way to create a new note without the link?

I remember seeing a similar question but I could not find it.

To remove the link from the template, add the following line to your init file (e.g., .emacs, .emacs.el, or .emacs.d/init.el).
(setq howm-template "= %title\n%date%cursor")

Here's another example of customization: place the cursor just before the link. Feel free to adjust the "..." part as needed.
(setq howm-template "= %title
%date%cursor %file

")

If you want to remove the link, you can also use "undo" (C-/, C-x u, etc.).

Ok, thanks. I tried M-x describe-variable RET howm-template RET but I did not understand the information on that screen. Can you explain the meaning of this (setq howm-template "= %title\n%date%cursor")?
